# InnerHits objects of not matched with whole query should not get in result in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my data Names and documents are nested objects.My data is

```
       {
           "id":"1234"
           "Names":{
                 "name":"Elasticseasrch,
                 "count":14
                },
           "documents":[{
                     "type":"pan",
                     "value"234234sdfsd"
                      },
                   {
                     "type":"passport",
                     "value"543543"
                      }
                     ]
           },

       {
           "id":"456"
           "Names":{
                 "name":"Kibana,
                 "count":6
                },
           "documents":[{
                     "type":"pan",
                     "value"6775675757"
                      },
                   {
                     "type":"passport",
                     "value"543543"
                      }
                     ]
           }
```

My query is this where id and either name or document must match. the resultant document contains the innerhit object of "456_doc"  where this is matched with document value ="234234sdfsd" where id is"1234" but not with "456". so I don't want "456_doc" innerhit object in the result.

```
                          {
                    "query": {
                         "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                  {
    "bool":{
      "must":[

          { "match": {
             "id":"1234"
            }
          },
          {
             "bool": {
                    "should": [
                                      {
           "nested": {
        "inner_hits": {
          "_source": true,
          "name":"1234_name"
        },
        "path": "Names",
          "query": {
            "match": {
             "Names.name":"Elasticsearch"
            }
            }
          }
          } ,
                                {
           "nested": {
        "inner_hits": {
          "_source": true,
          "name":"1234_doc"
        },
        "path": "documents",
          "query": {
            "match": {
             "documents.value":"234234sdfsd"
            }
            }
          }
          }
          ]
          }
          }
          ]
    }
    },
           {
    "bool":{
      "must":[

          { "match": {
             "id":"456"
            }
          },
          {
             "bool": {
                    "should": [
                                      {
           "nested": {
        "inner_hits": {
          "_source": true,
          "name":"456_name"
        },
        "path": "Names",
          "query": {
            "match": {
             "Names.name":"kibana"
            }
            }
          }
          } ,
                                {
           "nested": {
        "inner_hits": {
          "_source": true,
          "name":"456_doc"
        },
        "path": "documents",
          "query": {
            "match": {
             "documents.value":"234234sdfsd"
            }
            }
          }
          }
          ]
          }
          }
          ]
    }
    }
          ]
}
```

}
}

Comment: do you mean , you don't  this section to come when hit:[] inside it is zero "456_doc" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 0,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [ ]
            }
          }

Comment: 456_doc" : { "hits" : { "total" : { "value" : 2.7.., "relation" : "eq" }, "max_score" : null, "hits" : [{"_source": {
                    "type": "pan",
                    "values": [
                      "234234sdfsd",
                      "
                    ], ] } } .....i'm getting like this not zero.I'm getting values of "1234_doc" in"456_doc"

Comment: I don't think it is possible. It will include metadata fields , you will need to check for hits.total in client side

Comment: please once execute in elasticsearch...i'm getting "456_doc" with nonzero..because as it is a nested obj..matched withonly nested  query so it return ithink soo.but it does not matched with id. soo my expectation is "456_doc" hits should be zero

Comment: I am not able to get your issue. Here's what I tried. First I executed your query as it is , it returned zero records as match :id 456 and id 1234 are in must clause, so no documents will be returned then I removed first must clause and executed it , I received 1 match and inner hit 456_doc was returned with zero inner hits. Can you check your query as per two records you have posted in question and post full query , its actual output and expected output

Comment: Thank Jaspreet Chahal for your reply. This is issue not major now. can u look at this now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095575/need-innerhits-for-rescore-query-in-elasticsearch